# Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'UPPER', ¿por qué me sale este error?

Tags: php, mysql

Intento guardar los datos de un registro en mayúsculas en MYSQL, pero al momento de guardar los mismos, me sale este mensaje de error:

```
Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'UPPER'
```

El código que tengo es éste:

```
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO db_servicios (id_in, fecha_servicio, servicio_num, n_destino, n_vuelo, db_terminal, hora_llegada, hora_pickup, num_pax, nom_usuario, nombre_pax, nom_hotel, nom_cuenta, forma_pago, tipo_servicio1, nombre_proveedor, n_servicio, num_folio, comentarios_1, comentarios_2, comentarios_3, tipo_transporte, estatus_serv) VALUES (UPPER(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s))",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['id_in'], "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['fecha_servicio'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['servicio_num'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['n_destino'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['n_vuelo'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['db_terminal'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['hora_llegada'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['hora_pickup'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['num_pax'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['nom_usuario'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['nombre_pax'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['nom_hotel'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['nom_cuenta'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['forma_pago'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['tipo_servicio1'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['nombre_proveedor'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['n_servicio'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['num_folio'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['comentarios_1'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['comentarios_2'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['comentarios_3'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['tipo_transporte'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['estatus_serv'], "text"));

  $Result1 = mysqli_query($TC2P, $insertSQL) or die(mysqli_error($TC2P));

  $insertGoTo = "main.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
$insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
$insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
}
header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}
```

Si alguien me puede apoyar con este problema, se lo voy a agradecer. Saludos y buen día.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función UPPER sólo admite **un** parámetro. En este ejemplo.

```
VALUES (UPPER(%s, %s, %s ...
```

Debería ser:

```
VALUES (UPPER($s), UPPER($s), UPPER($s) ...
```

No estoy seguro de si esto solucionará tu problema, o si habrá otros que solventar, sin código / contexto suficiente es dificil de saber de antemano.

Comment: Gracias @Peter Petrov. Me funcionó así como sugieres. Saludos.